# How to play notification sound if a new entry is recorded in the database

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

So basically I have a written a PHP system with a MySQL database, where users can add calls to the database. The system then displays the calls in a table in order for newest first.

I am wanting to have a notification sound play automatically when a new call is added, and I have no idea where to start. It would also be cool if this would work on a iPad, but not sure if that is possible?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the **`<embed>`** tag to do this.

```
if($recordInsertedSuccessfully)
{
    echo "<embed src=".$pathtomyaudiofile." hidden=TRUE autostart=true></embed>";
}
```

Comment: okay so this is the code I now have, using the <embed> tag. **'code'** $result9=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Staff) AS RoomCount FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_live WHERE DateTimeAdded between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) and now()) AS f GROUP BY Staff ORDER BY COUNT(Staff) DESC LIMIT 1 "); 
   $count8 = mysql_result($result9, 0);
   
   if($count8 >= 1 {
   echo "<embed src="notification.m4r" hidden=TRUE autostart=true></embed>";
   }

Comment: did it work ? i am looking for a similar solution for my website

Answer (score 0):

Use [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html) to trigger when a new row is inserted. You can then insert a new row into a new table. Query the new table using any tool which plays the sound and remove the column after playing the sound.